# substitute one value with another from a different table in SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, puppet

I'm trying come up with a SQL statement to print all the duplicate [exported-resource] definition in the Puppet database.

```
mysql> SELECT id,restype,host_id,source_file_id FROM resources    
    -> WHERE title IN (SELECT title FROM resources WHERE exported=1 
    -> GROUP BY title HAVING count(title) > 1) ORDER BY title;
+------+------------------------+---------+----------------+
| id   | restype                | host_id | source_file_id |
+------+------------------------+---------+----------------+
|  305 | Nagios::Client::Export |       2 |             18 |
|  333 | Nagios_host            |       2 |             39 |
|  605 | Nagios_hostextinfo     |       6 |              2 |
|  443 | Nagios_hostextinfo     |       2 |             39 |
|  499 | Nagios_host            |       6 |              2 |
|  770 | Nagios::Client::Export |       6 |             18 |
......
......
```

Which is working just fine, but how can I retrieve/print *hosts.name* from *hosts* table in stead of the `host_id`. I just can't get my head around with rewriting the above SQL statement. The *hosts* table looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT id,name  FROM hosts;
+----+-----------------------------------------+
| id | name                                    |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|  2 | controller-dns-01.sdas.cloud.com        |
|  6 | controller-monitoring-01.sdas.cloud.com |
|  1 | controller-puppet.sdas.cloud.com        |
| 13 | talend-admin-01.sdas.cloud.com          |
| 15 | talend-jobserver-01.sdas.cloud.com      |
| 14 | talend-jobserver-02.sdas.cloud.com      |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
```

Also, is there a way to print only the first part of the *hostname* (i.e. only `controller-dns-01`) in stead of the complete string? Any suggestion from any one greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

---

**Update:**
This is my final command: Just in case if someone else also looking for a way to find out the Puppet Exported resources duplicate definitions

```
mysql> CREATE INDEX index_resources_on_restypetitle ON resources (restype(12),title(12));
mysql> SELECT r.id, r.restype, r.title, SUBSTRING_INDEX(h.name,'.',1) AS 'host_name',
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.filename,'puppet/',-1) AS 'file_name', r.line FROM resources r 
    -> LEFT JOIN hosts h ON r.host_id = h.id LEFT JOIN source_files s ON r.source_file_id = s.id 
    -> WHERE MD5(CONCAT(restype,title,host_id)) 
    -> IN (SELECT MD5(CONCAT(restype,title,host_id)) FROM resources 
    -> WHERE exported=1 GROUP BY MD5(CONCAT(restype,title,host_id)) 
    -> HAVING COUNT(MD5(CONCAT(restype,title,host_id))) > 1) ORDER BY title;
```

the `SUBSTRING_INDEX(s.filename....)` bit may needs readjusting according to the configuration. A big thank to thiella for helping me out.

Comment: Use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function to get the first part of the hostname.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks! Completely forgot about that SUBSTRING_INDEX() function. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to JOIN your `resources` table with your `hosts` table, using SUBSTRING_INDEX to show the part of the string at the left of the dot:

```
SELECT
  r.id, r.restype, r.host_id, r.source_file_id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(h.name, '.', 1)
FROM
  resources r LEFT JOIN hosts h
  ON r.host_id = h.id
WHERE
  r.title IN (SELECT title
            FROM resources
            WHERE export=1 
            GROUP BY title
            HAVING count(title) > 1)
ORDER BY
  r.title;
```

Comment: Thanks at lot, works just fine. I was thinking about `JOIN` but I always get confused with the way it works. Just one thing: it's taking more than one and half min `(28 rows in set (1 min 46.52 sec))` to finish on the table (resources) with only 1562 records. Is it normal? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers it should not be that slow... i would try to add an index on the title column, and also an index on hosts.id... cheers :)

Comment: Thanks again. Adding index on `title` brings the execution time down to 14 sec., which is a lot "expected" result. Cheers!!